# Customize the protractor test report/output

Tags: protractor

Hi I'm trying to get the protractor test results in a file by giving the following command in command prompt.
protractor conf.js > location\result.txt 
where I could see the complete output of the protractor test.

**Can I get just the number of Specs executed and failures in a txt file after running the protractor tests in a customized way?**

I need my report in this customized way as I need to run a shell script if all the protractor tests are passed.

Answer (score 10):

We have two ways to fulfill your requirement. but it will give final results in .json format. If you really needed only .txt format you convert .json to .text

**Ways To Do:**

1. Declare parameter '***resultJsonOutputFile:***' value in conf.js file as follows-

   *resultJsonOutputFile:'./testResults.json',*  //output file path to store the final results in .json format

**OR**

2. Pass the output file path from command line while running the protractor:

   **Command:**

   ```
     protractor --resultJsonOutputFile='../outputFilePath.json' protractor.conf.js
   ```

If you need any suggestions/help, please ping here, i'm happy to help you.

Comment: Suresh, this only provides spec caption, But not Suite. Can I have Suite description too in result json

Answer (score 4):

Jasmine is the framework that does the spec reporting, not Protractor.  You can either use one of the popular ones they already have:

(1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter

(2)https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters (look at the JUnit XML section)

Or you can make your own (which is what it sounds like you want): http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your `conf.js` file something like this.

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName: 'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['invoice.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
}
```

Then execute it using following comander.

```
npm install protractor-html-screenshot-reporter
```

Feel free to ask any questions if you are not clear. :)