# How to make a systematic report in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am working on protractor for testing an angularjs application. I am also able to fetch the report but I want to mention some more points and details about the test execution. For example Its model name, Test case name, Severity, Priority, Where the test failed if it gets fails etc. Where should I add all this points so that I can be able to fetch a complete detailed report.[Currently I am able to get the report I have attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uipj.png)

Please help me in getting the solution as I am new to protractor. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize the protractor test report/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985284/customize-the-protractor-test-report-output)

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine framework does specs reporting, not Protractor in e2e testing. You can either leverage some of the popular ones listed below or need to create your own using custom reporter.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter
- http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

Or you can try with Allure Report here https://allurereport.org/

Answer (score 0):

I also advice to use [Allure Report](https://allurereport.org/). It is easy to setup and has a good documentation. Just want to mention that there is Allure 2 is ready. Take a look at [GitHub](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) and [integration for JS](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-js)